# How to reset interline spacing for Azure Data Studio?

Tags: azure-data-studio

I have updated the interline spacing in ADS but can not find where/how I did that.  I searched for it in the Settings and did not find it. How can this be reset?

I also tried to open the Settings json according to the Microsoft Learn documentation [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-data-studio/settings) but that option  `Preferences: Open Current Profile Settings (JSON)` does not exist as stated on `macOS`.

Comment: Have you checked the JSON settings file? Some settings aren't exposed in the GUI, and only in the JSON.

Comment: @ThomA funny i was just updating the post to say I can't see how to open the settings json.  But actually i had updated the spacing in the gui somewhere

Comment: If the settings file doesn't exist, you don't have any settings set; it's using the default settings for the application (though I'm pretty sure that even then the settings.json file exists).

Comment: @ThomA  I think it exists because I had changed Font size: I just don't how to access it.

Comment: In the Settings menu (`Ctrl`+`,`) click the little file with the arrow on it in the top right.

Comment: @ThomA  Can you make an answer and add a screenshot?  I can't find it and detest gui's that force me to look for odds and ends icons for this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset interline spacing in Azure Data Studio, go to the settings of ADS as shown below:

[image]

In settings, search for "line," and you will get "line height" as shown below:

[image]

By default, it is set to 0. Increase it according to your requirement. For example, I increased it to 4 and got the space as shown below:

[image]

For more information, you can refer to [this](https://www.onexception.dev/news/1193031/interline-spacing-in-ads).